# How to use substring and charindex in google query language

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet sheet with several columns:

A: date
B: string
C: number
...
G: string (could be empty)
H: string (could be empty)

I would like to have a small table with the following:

Get the sum of C in table, where rows are the values of G (substring of it, as they are configured as this: CATEGORY:ITEM, I need grouping by CATEGORY only) and  columns are monts

So far I've got only partial solutions with query (for example group by month(toDate(A)) etc) - I seem to be unable to use substring and charindex nor left to do string manipulation to remove the item part after the category nor to visualize those as the first clumns in the resulting rows...

Edit: just to clear up a bit: I need to alter the value in G for each row so that I can group by the altered value. I know it is possible to do with dates ( in my example -> group by month(toDate(A)) gives me access to each value in A column so the result is grouped correctly for each separate month). But it seems string manipulation is not allowed?

How do I do that for starters.

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1--BLsvedGH43VwP-f20nSKFcmQrpb6lYx9LpOIgQ1eQ/edit?usp=sharing - example data is in sheet 1, desired look in sheet 2, row numbers should be as many as the distinct categories, columns should be as many as distinct months (up to 12 of course) - data is collected for 1 year so no need to consider one and same month twice.

Comment: Adjusting the input is not allowed, I can potentially add a hidden column that uses left+find to strip the item name, but it will make the sheets a lot bigger with a lot more calculations and potentially slower as there is data for at least 10 years in 10+ different accounts - I have to modify every single sheet (each sheet is one year collection) and in each spreadsheet (each spreadsheet a different file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your desired output, can you try this on sheet 2:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({day(Sheet1!A2:A10)&text(month(Sheet1!A2:A10), " (mmm)"), Sheet1!B2:F10, regexextract(Sheet1!G2:G10, "(.+):")}, "select Col7, sum(Col3) group by Col7 pivot Col1"))
```

and see if this is getting somewhere ?

Or in case you prefer open ended ranges:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({day(Sheet1!A2:A)&text(month(Sheet1!A2:A), " (mmm)"), Sheet1!B2:F, iferror(regexextract(Sheet1!G2:G, "(.+):"))}, "select Col7, sum(Col3) where Col7 <>'' group by Col7 pivot Col1"))
```

Comment: It is getting somewhere, but the pivoting is not correct, it create a column for each day of the month (so ~ 30 columns) - it should sum per month (so sum for CATEGORY for Jan, Feb etc, then sum for Category2 for jan, feb etc...). I am so sorry to ask for more but the formula is really complicated, if you could explain it a little bit I might be able to fir it? Thanks

Comment: Thanks that is fine, I needed grouping by month, so I changed the array, as far as I understand it what you did is to alter the data before passing it to the query functions, right? One question, when pivoting based on the Date, the sorting is wrong, it goes like month 10, month 11, month 12, then 2, 3, 4... etc, i.e. the sorting on columns is wrong, how do I fix that? Other than this it works perfectly fine

Comment: One more (hopefully last) question: in the resulting table when for a month there is no entry for a type the cell remains empty, how to fill it with a zero (0) so that charts work correctly?

Comment: Hi again Peter, you can fill in zeroes by checking for isblank(). The sorting should be okay if you just use the month numbers (no text). Can you check if something like this works for you: =ArrayFormula(if(isblank(query({Sheet1!A2:F, iferror(regexextract(Sheet1!G2:G, "(.+):"))}, "select Col7, sum(Col3) where Col7 <>'' group by Col7 pivot Month(Col1)+1")),0, query({Sheet1!A2:F, iferror(regexextract(Sheet1!G2:G, "(.+):"))}, "select Col7, sum(Col3) where Col7 <>'' group by Col7 pivot Month(Col1)+1") ))

Comment: Yes, with little tweaks I managed to get exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

been searching all over for a similar solution :-)

just in case you would like an alternative solution...
This works a treat based on my sheet H with data in column A to F

=transpose(split(textjoin("|",1,transpose({H!A1:F100})),"|"))

See... https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90629/concatenate-several-columns-into-one-in-google-sheets